# Default type class implementation in trait for sub-classes in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have the following relations:

```
trait Instrument

trait EquityOption extends Instrument { ... }
case class CallEquityOption(...) extends EquityOption
case class PutEquityOption(...) extends EquityOption

trait Priceable[I <: Instrument] { def price(I : Instrument) }
```

I can use exactly the same implementation of `Priceable` for the case classes `CallEquityOption`and `PutEquityOption`. By having a `match case` to differentiation between the `Call...` and `Put...`. However, if I try to implement it directly as `Priceable[EquityOption]` under `object EquityOption`, the implicit cannot be found since it doesn't exactly match the type.

How can I make it work without needing to duplicate code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to prove that you can provide an instance for every subtype of `EquityOption`.

```
implicit def allEquityOptions[T <: EquityOption]: Pricable[T] = ???
```